# TypeScript type inference issue with generic hook function and FilterType

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a generic hook function useFilters that handles filtering based on a given set of filter keys. The function should provide a setFilterByKey function and a filters object with the corresponding filtered values.

However, I'm encountering issues with the TypeScript type inference for the filters object and the setFilterByKey function. Here's the relevant code:

```js
const CUSTOM_FILTER_KEYS = [{
    key: 'status',
    type: 'string',
    multi: true,
  },
  {
    key: 'price',
    type: 'number',
    multi: false,
  },
] as
const;

type FilterValueType = 'string' | 'number'
type FilterKeyDefinition < K extends string > = {
  key: K;
  type: FilterValueType;
  multi: boolean;
};
type FilterValue < T extends string | number > = T | undefined | null;

type FilterType < FilterKey extends FilterKeyDefinition < string >> = {
  [K in FilterKey['key']] ? : Extract < FilterKey,
  {
    key: K
  } > ['multi'] extends true ?
  Extract < FilterKey,
  {
    key: K
  } > ['type'] extends 'number' ?
  FilterValue < number > [] :
  FilterValue < string > [] :
    Extract < FilterKey,
  {
    key: K
  } > ['type'] extends 'number' ?
  FilterValue < number >
  :
    FilterValue < string > ;
};

const useFilters = < K extends string > (filterKeys: readonly FilterKeyDefinition < K > []) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const filters = useMemo(
    () => filterKeys.reduce((prevFilters, {
        key,
        type,
        multi
      }) => {
        let value: FilterValue < string | number > | FilterValue < string | number > [];

        if (multi) {
          value = mapMultiValue(searchParams.getAll(key), type);
        } else {
          value = mapSingleValue(searchParams.get(key), type);
        }

        (prevFilters as any)[key] = value;

        return prevFilters;
      }, {}
      as Partial < FilterType < typeof filterKeys[number] >> ), [searchParams, filterKeys],
  );

  const setFilterByKey = (key: K, value: FilterType < typeof filterKeys[number] > [K]) => {
    setSearchParams({
      ...searchParams,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };

  return {
    setFilterByKey,
    filters
  };
};

const getNumberValue = (value: FilterValue < string > ) => (Number.isNaN(value) ? undefined : Number(value));

const mapSingleValue = (value: FilterValue < string > , type: FilterValueType) => {
  if (type === 'number') {
    return getNumberValue(value);
  }

  return value;
};

const mapMultiValue = (values: FilterValue < string > [], type: FilterValueType) => {
  if (type === 'number') {
    return <number[] > values.map(getNumberValue).filter((value) => !_.isNil(value));
  }

  return <string[] > values.filter((value) => !_.isNil(value));
};
```

The problem is that the inferred types for filters.status and filters.price are not correct. They should be FilterValue[] | undefined and FilterValue[] | undefined, respectively. Similarly, the setFilterByKey function should expect the correct types for key and value.

I have tried various approaches, including explicit type annotations, but I haven't been successful in resolving these type inference issues.

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing these problems and suggest a solution to ensure correct type inference for filters and setFilterByKey?